# compare 2 cells and update result in another cell in excel using xlwt python

Tags: python, xlrd, xlwt, xlutils

I have excel that `col A` and `col B` like below:

```
  A       B   
 KIWI   KIWI
 APPLE  APPLE
 ORANGE  BANANA
```

I need to compare the contents in col A and col B and if they matches write match/not match in col C like below.

```
  A         B        C
 KIWI    KIWI     Matched
 APPLE   APPLE    Matched
 ORANGE  BANANA   Not Matched
```

I am using `xlwt` to write excel.I can use `xlrd` to read and `xlwt` to write again.But to do this I need to open the same sheet twice.

please help me is there any better way to do this .

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an if compare formula in column C instead =if(a1=b1,matched, not matched)?

Comment: pls share an example to better explain what `IF` formula you are trying to mention here; because =if(a1... also has an IF formula.